# HTTP error when uploading large size images

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to upload an image using the WordPress Media Uploader (WP Admin > Media > Add new). Smaller size image up to 460kb uploading fine without any error. But when i try to upload large size image it showing HTTP error. I have tried adding the below line in wp-config file. But No luck :(

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64MB');
```

Anyone have idea on this. Please help me.
[I have attached screenshot too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37tSS.png)

Thanks..

Comment: May be you have restriction on your web server for file size. Check `phpinfo()` output.

Comment: Maximum upload file size is 25 MB.

Answer (score 0):

In your wordpress dashboard go to **Settings -> Media**. There you have different sizes (width x height) defined for Thumbnails, Medium Size and Large. By default, for large wordpress has a size of 1024 x 1024. If you try to upload a bigger resolution image like 4096 x 2048 let's say, you'll get an error. Try increasing the resolution for the Large images and try again and see if that works. Check `phpinfo()` for memory_limit settings on your server. If it's limited to some amount at the server level, setting it on **wp-config.php** won't really help.